# Xcode/Phonegap not compiling the right version of my app

Tags: xcode, mobile, cordova

When I compile my mobile app using Xcode and Phonegap, the application on the iPod/iPhone/iPad is the anterior version that I compiled yesterday.

Basically when I run the app in the emulator, all works fine, so I know it's the right files and everything, but when I then build it for the mobile device, it shows the one I did yesterday.

What could be causing this? Is there any settings I should check or something? Like I said I doubt it's related to the files/folder because when emulating it, it works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem long time ago. Try to delete your app on the device and then build it again. I don't know how apple manage apps but I think that the major of your app is keeped on your device (in order to speed up compilation).
I hope it will works !

Comment: Sorry for not updating. I used the Clean function and all worked great. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Did you increase the version number of your built? If you recompile with the same number, you may run into trouble.